# Sharepoint columns with unique values validation

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Sharepoint online list which is going to cross the the threshold limit very soon. I am just curious about the the two columns which have "enforce unqiue values"  option enabled.

Will these columns keep working with the validation even if the list has crossed more than 5000 items? I am asking this because you can't enable unique validation for a column if the list already has crossed the threshold. But in my case i have enabled it from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable enforce unique values from the beginning, when the list reaches the threshold limit, it still works.

Besides, it is not suggested to have more than 5000 item in a library.

Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint for your reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59#ID0EAABAAA=Online